# Bash script does not execute commands until after delay

Tags: bash, shell-script

I created a script to type a random string of numbers by binding it to a hotkey:

```
#!/bin/bash

ran="$(shuf -i 100000-999999 -n 1)"

sleep .2

xdotool type --delay 12 "untitled_$ran "
```

For some reason, the `xdotool` command will not do anything for the first tenth of a second or so. If there is no `sleep`, nothing is typed. If the `sleep` command is shorter, fewer than six characters are typed. It's as if the command runs, but is ignored for the first few moments after the script is executed.

**Why does this happen,** and how can I resolve this?

Comment: There is no intrinsic reason why this should happen. How are you launching the script? Is there perhaps a keyboard focus change right after you do? Or are you running the script from a shell in the same terminal that imminently expects to receive the keypresses? By the way, your script is Bourne-compatible, so you could be using `#!/bin/sh` for greater portability.

Comment: @HaukeLaging How exactly is `shuf` an "extremely bad way"? `shuf` uses only a small amount of entropy for initialization and is pseudorandom. It's much better than  `$RANDOM`, which doesn't even get seeded randomly and uses the current date instead. If you're concerned about code elegance, `shuf` is also more fitting since it doesn't require all kinds of arithmetic to get into a proper value range.

Comment: @PawkyPenguin I misunderstood the way `shuf` works. I will delete the comment.

Comment: @HaukeLaging No worries. It's actually a good point that the source of randomness matters. In `shuf`'s case, I'm fairly sure that the PRG only gets initialized at startup (or maybe the first time `shuf` is executed), because if I execute it multiple times in a row, my available entropy still doesn't go down.

Comment: @Celada I'm firing the script from a hotkey, using the keyboard utility present in Linux Mint Cinnamon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said in a comment that you are using some kind of hotkey to trigger this script. I can't be sure what's happening, but I suspect that the keyboard focus is being moved around and that `xdotool`, when run without delay, is being run while the focus is something other than the intended terminal. I recommend the following method for testing this hypothesis:

- Start `xev` from a terminal.
- Focus the `xev` window (move the mouse into it, or such) while keeping the terminal visible.
- Press your hotkey.
- Watch for `FocusOut` and `FocusIn` events recorded by `xev`. If any of these happen, they could explain why `xev` is missing keypresses.
- `KeyPress` and `KeyRelease` events should show you `xdotool` doing its work.

If the hypothesis is correct, then as for how to resolve it, you'd have to  activate the hotkey in some way that doesn't cause a focus change. I don't know...

Comment: Yep, I do see a change in focus when hitting my hotkey. This seems to explain the issue, and lines up with what I said about needing a delay at the start of the script.